# Partial Parameter Estimation (MLE/LMMSE)

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have a basic question. MLE/LMSSE is introduced as follows:
$$Y = H\theta + W$$
where $H$ is the linear model matrix, $W$ is measurement noise (let's assume it is normal so MLE = LMSSE). $\theta$ is the vector of parameters.

The ML estimate is well-known: $(H'H)^{-1}H'\bf{Y} = \widehat{\theta}\quad\quad$ ($\bf{Y}$ is the vector of observations.)

Let's say I am only interested estimating one of the parameters (say the first parameter).
Is it equal to the first entry of $\widehat{\theta}$?

More generally is the ML estimate of $S\theta$ where $S$ is some low-rank matrix the same as $S\widehat{\theta}$? I do not think that is the case, but I don't know how exactly to deal with it.

Comment: Cross posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858695/partial-parameter-estimation-mle-lmmse

Comment: I suggested to close the cross-posted question above on math (first voter). We should try to not close it on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

The posterior distribution over $\theta$ is Gaussian here.

When you apply the linear function $\theta\mapsto S\theta$ to it, the new random variable $S\theta$ is still Gaussian, so its MLE is just its expectation, and $\mathbb{E}[S\theta] = S\mathbb{E}[\theta]$.

Comment: Thanks... I dont have a good theoretical background in estimation theory. Let me try to rework this one with this pointer. I will get back to you.

Comment: I think I am getting a little confused. As I understand the linear model changes. I guess it would help if you could point me to some tutorial on MLE.   or a proof :) THanks

Comment: @user161378 The way you phrased the question is that you estimate the whole model (all $\theta$'s), then take a subset, which is what I answered. If instead you change your model to _only_ consider one of the parameters, then of course the estimate will be different; the new model matrix will be just the first column of the original matrix.